# Link containers on cockpit

Tags: docker, lxc

I think this is a pretty common scenario, but I don't seem to find a solution. Given: 1. A container with an application that requires a database, 2. A database container; I need to link those containers so the application uses the database.

I have fedora server, and using cockpit for managing images/containers is really straightforward, but I can't link containers (or even set environment variables).

Is there something I'm missing? I **have to** install Kubernetes for this?

Comment: Well.. I found this issue, with a PR, but they were closed without an apparent reason: https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/issues/1665

Comment: It's not "closed without an apparent reason". The reason was obvious. It was "petervo closed this issue from a commit"!

Comment: @MichaelHampton you are right, just realized about that, I was looking for some "merged" message. The sad thing is that master is a bit unstable, I think I'll just wait :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was introduced on a recent version of cockpit, Fedora 21 ships an old version. Manually installing a new version of cockpit fixed the issue.